# optimize-storage pool fails, cluster upgrade in process

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-cluster, storage-spaces

I have a windows failover cluster running Server 2016 for a SQL 2017 Enterprise Availability Group. We have no shared disks on the server, just separate storage on each machine for the SQL AG. On both sides of the cluster, we've got storage spaces running stripes of 1TB disks for storage. (This is in azure, so it's stripes of P30 disks.)

I need to add capacity to the stripe, so I added 1 additional 1TB disk to the storage pool, and then tried to run the optimize-storagepool command to spread the data onto the new disk, but it failed. The error message I get looks like this:

```
        Optimize-StoragePool : The operation is not supported while the cluster is being upgraded.
    Activity ID: {b2a5cd56-0d4a-4904-92b7-1b6a4ccb7203}
    At line:1 char:1
    + Optimize-StoragePool -InputObject $pool
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...SFT_StoragePool) [Optimize-StoragePool], CimEx
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 40009,Optimize-StoragePool
```

... but our cluster is not being "upgraded." How do I get past this, and make the cluster know that it's no longer being upgraded? Or can I force the opimize-storagepool to happen some other way?